# Unparent Bone and current bone keep transform

Tags: modeling, python, bones

How do I unparent bone from its parent bone but keep unparanted bone and its child bones transform and rotation?

If I unparent bone, unparanted bone and its children change their position and rotation. I wish to keep it.

Will appreciate script for that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Control + A is a keyboard shortcut for applying a changed bone position as it's rest position in 'Pose Mode' (Maybe when you cut the posed position, it reverts back to it's rest position that you created it at?)

Control + A in object mode applies rotation, scale, and location.